# Covering of a Topological Group(Use of fundamental theorem of covering spaces)

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose we have two path-connected spaces $G$ and $H$. Suppose also that $G$ is a topological group with an identity element $e$ and there is a covering $$ p: H \rightarrow G $$ 
The problem asks that we choose an element $f$ in the fiber of $e$ to be the identity element of $H$ and show $H$ to be a topological group. I was able to find a map $$f:H \times H \rightarrow G$$ via the composition of the multiplication on $G$ and $p \times p$. There is a theorem referred to within the book I am using which states that there is a map $H\times H \rightarrow H$  when $$f_{*}(\pi_{1}(H \times H, (f,f)) \subseteq p_{*}(\pi_{1}(H,f))$$

I am having trouble carefully showing this containment. I am wondering if this containment makes use of the continuous multiplication on $G$. This is a problem in Peter May's Concise Course on Algebraic Topology, so everything has some categorical framework. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $f:H\times H\rightarrow G\times G\rightarrow G$, where the second map is the product in $G$.  The first map will map $\pi_1(H\times H)$ into $p_*(\pi_1(H))\times p_*(\pi_1(H))$.  Since $p_*(\pi_1(H))$ is a subgroup, the multiplication map will map $p_*(\pi_1(H))\times p_*(\pi_1(H))$ into $p_*(\pi_1(H))$.

Comment: Wow, okay, I completely missed the closure property of subgroups. Thank you.

Comment: A small detail to help someone in looking at this in the future: For point wise multiplication of paths is equivalent to composition of paths. In the above framework:  For loops $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\pi_{1}(H)$. We have a point-wise multiplication of $\alpha*\beta(t)=\alpha(t)\beta(t)$

Comment: @user135520 Thanks. It's a quite important detail. Fortunately it's easy to construct a homotopy $F(t,s)$ between $(\alpha*\beta)(t)$ and $\alpha(t)\beta(t)$.